# uicollection view crash

Tags: ipad, uicollectionview

I've got this [UICollectionView](http://foo.com) set up with the [NSMutableArrays](http://foo.com) as datasource.
The problem is that it crashes on ipad simulator while scrolling down with having multiple  sections however it runs on device.
i am totally stuck with that and finding no solution to this problem anywhere.
The exception which xcode throwing is:
terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: You can see where it goes wrong with exception breakpoints. What do you see if you add one?

Comment: how about telling others how you solved it. so it might help them in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue might be experienced because of the use of XCode beta release. Try using the latest stable release of XCode and issue with simulator only will hopefully go away.